# How to traverse a linked list in c without destroying it in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, traversal

I know that to traverse I can make a temp linked list and go:

```
while (temp->next!=NULL){
    ...}
```

However, what if I want to change one position of my actual lists while traversing it?
The only way I can think of is to traverse the actual linked list  from the head, but wouldn't it destroy my linked list after it reaches the end?

Comment: Keep a copy of the point you started from, and you'll be OK.

Comment: @Floris hmm and then?

Comment: Make a copy of the initial pointer. Use this copy to iterate in the same way. The initial pointer has now not been touched, and nothing is "destroyed".

Comment: I have written out explicitly what @Quirliom was saying (which in turn expanded on what I said in my initial comment). Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume you have a list `myList`, and `myList.head` points to the first element:

```
temp = myList.head;
while (temp->next!=NULL){
  // do stuff with this element
  ...
  temp = temp->next; // get the next element
  }
```

Now you can go right back and do it again - `myList` is still the same, and

```
temp = myList.head;
```

gets you right back to the beginning again.

Comment: Looks like a `for` loop: `for (node * p = myList.head; p->next; p = p->next) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @KerrekSB you are right- that would make the intent much clearer. I prefer explicit condition `p->next != NULL;` over the implicit `!p->next;` (I think you forgot the `!`) but that's a matter of style.

Comment: It would also leak less scope and make multiple continuation points less error-prone to write :-)

Comment: @Floris p->next in the condition part of the for loop implicitly means p->next != NULL. Doesn't it?

Comment: @soumendas yes you are right - but stating it explicitly avoids lots of mistakes (like the one I made above...) Clarity trumps brevity.